# using Set.has in Array.filter - incompatible receiver

Tags: javascript, this

Suppose I've a `Set` as a lookup table.

```
const myset = new Set(["key1", "key2", "key3", "keepMe"]);
```

I wanted to filter another array of some other keys (say `mykeys`) which are in `myset`.

```
const mykeys = ["ignoreMe", "keepMe", "ignoreMeToo", "key2"];
```

Question:

Why do I have to use

```
const filtered = mykeys.filter(k => myset.has(k))
```

instead of

```
const filtered = mykeys.filter(myset.has)
// TypeError: Method Set.prototype.has called on incompatible receiver undefined
```

i.e., why do I've to create an anonymous lambda function in filter? `keys.has` has same signature (argument - element, return boolean). A friend told me it's related to `this`.

Whereas `mykeys.map(console.log)` works without error (although not being of much use).

I came across this [article at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Called_on_incompatible_type) and I still don't get why "'myset' is not captured as this". I understand the workaround but not the "why". Can anyone explain it with some details and references in a human friendly way?

**Update:** Thank you all for the responses. Maybe I wasn't clear about what I'm asking. I do understand the workarounds.

@charlietfl understood. Here's [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544029/using-set-has-in-array-filter-incompatible-receiver/50544361#comment88099675_50544029), the thing I was looking for:

> Because filter() has no implicit `this` where as `set.has` needs to have proper `this` context. Calling it inside anonymous function and manually adding argument makes the call self contained.

Comment: Try `mykeys.filter(myset.has.bind(myset))` ... which is actually more to write than using the anonymous arrow function

Comment: I understand the workarounds. But I'm interested in knowing the "why" part :)

Comment: Because context of `this` in `filter()` is not the Set

Comment: Any references to understand this one better? I don't mean to be clingy, but why is the "context of `this` in `filter` is not the set"?

Comment: See if this helps https://jsfiddle.net/2n2ea6ea/1

Comment: Thank you sir! It does help. But I'm still not clear on the "why" `this` would be window here. Maybe I need to read more (maybe the spec)

Comment: Because filter() has no implicit `this` where as set.has needs to have proper `this` context. Calling it inside anonymous function and manually adding argument makes the call self contained

Comment: @charlietfl well this one line is much more helpful than anything :)
So it is how it got implemented in language. Any specific reasons?

Comment: [How does the `this` keyord work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) As for "why"...who knows. Just have to know how it does work

Answer (score 1):

This is a fundamental design decision dating back to the first definition of the JavaScript language.

Consider an object

```
var myObjet = {
  someValue: 0,
  someFunction: function() {
    return this.someValue;
  }
};
```

Now, when you write

```
var myValue = myObject.someValue;
```

You get exactly what you have put in it, as if you had written

```
var myValue = 0;
```

Similarly, when you write

```
var myFunction = myObject.someValue;
```

You get exactly what you have put in it, as if you had written

```
var myFunction = (function() {
  return this.someValue;
});
```

...except now, you are not in an object anymore. So `this` doesn't mean anything. Indeed, if you try

```
console.log(myFunction());
```

you will see

```
undefined
```

exactly as if you had written

```
console.log(this.someValue);
```

outside of any object.

So, what is `this`? Well, JavaScript decides it as follows:

- If you write `myObject.myFunction()`, then when executing the `myFunction()` part, `this` is `myObject`.
- If you just write `myFunction()`, then `this` is the current global object, which is generally `window` (not always, there are many special cases).
- A number of functions can inject a `this` in another function (e.g. `call`, `apply`, `map`, ...)

Now, why does it do this? The answer is that this is necessary for prototypes. Indeed, if you now define

```
var myDerivedObject = Object.create(myObject);
myDerivedObjet.someValue = 42;
```

you now have an object based on `myObject`, but with a different property 
`someValue`

```
console.log(myObject.someFunction()); // Shows 0
console.log(myDerivedObject.someFunction()); // Shows 42
```

That's because `myObject.someFunction()` uses `myObject` for `this`, while `myDerivedObject.someFunction()` uses `myDerivedObject` for `this`.

If `this` had been captured during the definition of `someFunction`, we would have obtained `0` in both lines, but this would also have made prototypes much less useful.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `thisArg` of [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with the set and the prototype of `has` as callback.

This pattern does not require a binding of an instance of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to the prototype, because

> If a `thisArg` parameter is provided to `filter`, it will be used as the callback's `this` value.  Otherwise, the value `undefined` will be used as its this value. The `this` value ultimately observable by `callback` is determined according to [the usual rules for determining the this seen by a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

```js
const
    myset = new Set(["key1", "key2", "key3", "keepMe"]),
    mykeys = ["ignoreMe", "keepMe", "ignoreMeToo", "key2"],
    filtered = mykeys.filter(Set.prototype.has, myset);

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: thanks for reminding me about existence of `thisArg`. I'll update my question as this is not what I'm looking for :)